# I see missing faces when I export from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I made a cube in Blender.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sIv.jpg.
In Blender everything look OK. The problem start when I exoprt this .fbx file to unity. There is missing faces from different views. I try anything: merge verticals, remove double faces, change the Normals in Unity to calculate, backface culling, recalculate normals (inside, outside and flip).
How it looks in Unity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng9j9.png.
Unity 2018.3.0f2, Blender 2.8 Beta, Eevee.

Can you give tips to prevent that?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145751/display-face-normal-direction-in-blender-2-8) if it helps.

Comment: Are these backfaces? Unity uses backface culling so if you look at the back of a face it will become transparent. Blender has an option to enable backface culling so you can see them already in blender as well. As a first fix: Make sure all normals are pointing outwards on your model...

Answer (score 2):

If your faces aren't showing up because of backface culling, you can recalculate normals in blender by hitting Ctrl+Shift+N in edit mode. Make sure to deselect "Inside" in the pop up. This should get fix the missing faces. To prevent this from occurring in the first place, make sure to do modeling for game engines with the backface culling option checked in blender so you can see when the normals are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems in the past. For me, the problem was with materials. When I exported my model from blender, for some reason the materials were missing and/or applied incorrectly after importing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've combined meshes then you may have a duplicate material in a second slot applied to the offending polygons.  There are various other cases where this can occur.

These won't show in Unity unless you've specified a secondary material for them within Unity itself, or you're creating them automatically from the FBX.  Personally I avoid the Unity automated options since they just create lots of duplicate garbage.

To fix this:

In the Blender Outliner change to Blender File view and delete one of the duplicate materials, then reapply the remaining one to all polys in your mesh and do whatever other cleanup you wish.  Be sure to fix any references to the duplicate material you deleted across any other objects.

If you are importing materials from the FBX to Unity you may have duplicate garbage materials within Unity as well, which is why I'd recommend not using that option since those materials are tied to the meshes as imported if the checkbox is enabled.